# ModelForm in template with a grouped choice field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a grouped category field. The problem is that I've created a search form, but when I try presente the form to the user in the template, it goes wrong.

models.py

```
MEDIA_CHOICES = (
    ('Audio', (
        ('vinyl', 'Vinyl'),
        ('cd', 'CD'),
    )
    ),
    ('Video', (
        ('vhs', 'VHS Tape'),
        ('dvd', 'DVD'),
    )
    ),
    ('unknown', 'Unknown'),
)

category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=MEDIA_CHOICES, verbose_name=_(u'Category'))
```

forms.py (search)

```
class SearchingForm(forms.Form):

    "Search Box"
    search = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, label=(_(u'Search')))

    music_kind = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=MEDIA_CHOICES, required=False,
                                        label=(_(u'Kind')),    
                                        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
                                        )
```

template.html

```
    {{ form.search }}
    {{ form.place_kind }}
```

I show the form to the user like this, the problem is when I rendered with a browser I have something like this (in each line, it has a checkbox):

```
(('vinyl', 'Vinyl'), ('cd', 'CD'))
(('vhs', 'VHS Tape'), ('dvd', 'DVD'))
Unknown
```

I have delete the 'widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()' attribute it goes right, but I don't have a checkboxes. So, How I can do it with checkbox fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a data type mismatch here. You're wanting to store multiple values in a single CharField. Sure, you could save a dictionary of key-value pairs in there, but then you'd have to parse it back out into selections, and that's a huge pain.

I would move your MEDIA_CHOICES to a database table, and then in your SearchingForm, you can do a CheckboxSelectMultiple, and the form will behave as expected.

Comment: It's a great idea, but How i can recover the data from the database. This should be done, in the view, as a query to the database?

Comment: You'll need to use a ModelMultipleChoiceField, which has a queryset property to hold the choices. Then you can use CheckboxSelectMultiple to override the widget.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I wonder if choice groups are only for select boxes (not checkboxes).

Comment: Yes, only are for select boxes, but I'm trying to reuse code. In this case, I should rewrite another choice field.